# Getting Error: Unknown property 'ContactStandardController.conList'

Tags: apex, visualforce

VF:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock title="Edit Contact">
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                <apex:inputField value="{!contact.FirstName}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!contact.LastName}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!contact.Email}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="save"/>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="cancel"/>
             </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!conList}" var="c">
                <apex:column headerValue="First Name">
                <apex:outputField value="{!c.Firstname}" />
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Last Name">
                <apex:outputField value="{!c.Lastname}" />
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Email">
                <apex:outputField value="{!c.Email}" />
                </apex:column>
          </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Apex:

```
public with sharing class ContactEditController {
    public contact c {get; set;}
    public List<contact> conList {get;set;}
    public ContactEditController(){
        c= new Contact();   
    }
    public PageReference save(){
        insert c;
        conList= [select FirstName,LastName,Email from Contact where id=:c.id];
        return null;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You are missing the extension in your VF page.

Your first line should be

`<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="ContactEditController" />`

However, unless you make a quick change to your controller, this won't work either. You have to implement a constructor (that the page will use)

```
public ContactEditController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
  //Initialize your contact variable here
}
```

For more details, visit [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_extension.htm) page.